# can you edit a pre-existing message embed object in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a question: is it possible to edit a pre-existing message embed object?

let's say you have an embed

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Embed Title`)
    .setDescription("Embed Description")
    .setColor("GREEN")
```

What if I want to change the description value without changing the code above?

Maybe there is a way to do it, like

```
embed.edit.description = 'new embed description';
```

I really have no idea, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just set the corresponding field again, and it'll overwrite the old value!

Just do `embed.setDescription('new embed description')` after defining `embed`, and using `embed` again should return the new value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the embed before sending the message with embed content, you can use:

```
// ORIGINAL EMBED
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Example title")
  .setDescription("Example description")
  .setColor("#00FF00");

// Then, to edit, for example, with a condition, inserting inside an IF block:
embed.setDescription("Edited description example");
```

Embed editing example:

```
if (message.content.includes("on")) {
  embed.setDescription("It's on!")
} else {
  embed.setDescription("It's off")
};
```